# Error: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement in command.ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: c#, ms-access

I get the error `Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement` in following line `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`

BTW, I already red some similar posts and I tried to fix my problem but I could not able to do so.

My database is `MS Access`.

Any help will be great!

```
private void btn_register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_name.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_family.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Some information is missed");
            }
            else
            {
                this.Hide();
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = " insert into Login (FirstName,FamilyName,UserName,PassWord,RepeatPassword,Email,MaxTime,LearningStyle) values ('" + txt_name.Text + "','" + txt_family.Text + "','" + txt_username.Text + "','" + txt_password.Text + "','" + txt_repeat.Text + "','" + txt_mail.Text + "','" + UpDownTime.Value + "','" + UpDownLearningStyle.Value + "')";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Your Registeration was successfull !");
                connection.Close();
                Login F1 = new Login();
                F1.Show();  

            }

        }
```

Comment: Debug and copy the value of CommandText i.e. constructed query and run it in Access directly. Does it work? Did you try that?

Comment: Also note that, saying *I tried to fix my problem but I could not* is not sufficient, you need to actually show what you tried!

Comment: More important, you should **always** use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. And use `using` statement to dispose your connection and command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. maybe it could help

Password is a reserved keyword

```
command.CommandText = " insert into Login (FirstName,FamilyName,UserName,PassWord,RepeatPassword,Email,....
```

try this

```
command.CommandText = " insert into Login (FirstName,FamilyName,UserName,[PassWord],RepeatPassword,Email,.....
```